# How to create and update the same list from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

i have two lists:

```
 a= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','4','to','the','words']
 b = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2]]
```

Now i need another list that updates value like:

```
 c = ['a','b','c'] w.r.t list of list in b
 c = ['d','e','f','4','to'] #update new list by removing previous one
 c = ['the','words']
 and so on......
```

How do i update list as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not extremely clear but it seems you're looking for something like this:

You can keep an offset of the index to add elements to new lists based on the indices provided.

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','4','to','the','words']
b = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2]]

last_offset = 0
cs = []
for bi in b:
  cs.append([a[bii + last_offset - 1] for bii in bi])
  last_offset += max(bi)
print(cs)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
a= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','4','to','the','words']
b = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2]]
c= []
start = 0
for ele in b:
    end = len(ele) + start
    c.append(a[start:end])
    start = end
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help?

```
a= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','4','to','the','words']
b = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2]]
itr_list = iter(a)
for mini_list in b:
    try:
        res = [next(itr_list) for _ in mini_list]
    except StopIteration:
        print(res)
        break
    print(res)
```

This code takes `a` and make it iterator thus you can ask for the next value from it using the command next. This will help if you have problems with the values in `b` and the length of `a`.

However it seems that `b` is redundant and you can just give an integer with the number of values to get from `a`.
If this was your intentions than you could use something like this:

```
a= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','4','to','the','words']
b = [3,5,2]

i=0
for val in b:
    print(a[i:val+i])
    i=val
```

Another feature that might be required is that maybe you want parallel values from `a`. For that to work you must use lists in `b`:

```
a= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','4','to','the','words']
b = [[1,2,3],[1,2,4,5],[6,7,1]]

for mini_list in b:
    print([a[val-1] for val in mini_list])
```

This code uses the values of `b` as indexes in `a`. you should notice that I reduces 1 because of [zero-base numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).